# How to access the Microsoft Resource Management API as a service using OAuth2.0

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rest-api

I am developing a time-triggered service that fetches data from various API's and writes it to a database.
One of the API's I need to access is the Microsoft Resource Management API. However, the problem is that its endpoints all mention the OAuth2.0 explicit grant flow- which requires a user to log in. Since I am creating a automated service, I cannot use that flow.

For example, the list resource group endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resource-groups/list) mentions the Oauth2 implicit grant flow with the user_impersonation scope:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XmIW.png

Is it even possible to get data from this API as a service, and if so, how would I go about doing that? Is there any other way I could get a list of resource groups and resources from the Azure platform?

I do succesfully utilize the OAuth2.0 client credientials grant flow to authenticate with  the Graph API as a service, but that does not seem possible here.

Comment: `I tried accessing the endpoint using the OAuth client credentials grant flow I use to retrieve tokens for other API's, but that results in a 401.` - Please edit your question and provide more details about this.

Comment: @GauravMantri thanks, what would you like to have clarified? Should the client credential flow be able to work with this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call Azure Management REST API, you need to generate access token with scope as **`https://management.azure.com/.default`**.

I registered  one Azure AD application and added **API permission** as below:

[image]

> Make sure to add **proper RBAC role** to above service principal under subscription.

In my case, I added **`Reader`** role to the service principal under subscription like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this access token to call below Management API query, I got **list of resource groups** successfully in response like this:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourcegroups?api-version=2021-04-01
```

**Response:**
[image]

Comment: This works for me, thanks a lot! It turned out that I did not have the proper RBAC role assigned to the app registration.